# Magento 1.9 : Update native field properties

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, fieldsets

I've just finished building an extended password policy module, which allows for customisable control over the rules for creating/updating a password.

The general idea is that you can set the minimum characters, whether the password should contain a special character, uppercase character, etc...

The module works as expected, however, there is no indication to the admin what rules he needs to follow when creating/updating an account.

I've found the form I need to update, `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main`, and the field that needs editting and the property that needs adding:

```
$fieldset->addField('password', 'password', array(
    ....
    'after_element_html' => '<small># Output Rules Here #</small>',
));
```

My problem is I don't really want to extend the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main` class and rewrite the entire `_prepareForm()` method, it'd be preferable to target that particular form and that particular field and update the properties, but I can't seem to find out if that is even possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to update the field theough jQuery once the form elements are loaded in page?

Comment: Ideally not, would be looking more for a way to extend the core.